# Make a div content "addable" but not "removable"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, prose-mirror

so I'm creating a Rich text editor using React Remirror (https://remirror.io/) component. Right now, I'd like to create a "system" in which a text that was initally loaded to the editor will be editable in a sense that a user can add text to it, but can't remove from it. There are several options I tried but all seem really overcomplicated for such a thing. I know about the `contenteditable="false"` directive but it makes the whole paragraph just not removable and not addable at all. Is there any easy way of doing such things or do I have to create a Remirror's custom extension with some fancy logic for that?

@Edit, due to @Konrad's comment -> preventing the backspace event won't work, as I want the added text to be editable

Comment: So the user won't be able to press backspace?

Comment: do you have a codesandbox?

Comment: @Konrad my bad, didn't give a full info - preventing the backspace event won't work, as I want the added text to be editable